# What's the origin of the expression "(can't) hack it"?

Tags: etymology

[image]

[From Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/cant-hack-it):

> phrase
>
> If you say that someone *can't hack it* or *couldn't hack it*, you
> mean that they do not or did not have the qualities needed to do a
> task or cope with a situation.
>
> [informal]
>
> You have to be strong and
> confident, and never give the slightest impression that you can't hack
> it.
>
> hack
>
> *COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright ©
> HarperCollins Publishers*

Is it only a variation of  "(can't) cut it" or does it trace its roots
back to another place?

Comment: it's astonishing you did not realize that: the image you posted was tremendously too large beyond social norms.

Comment: It's a phone screenshot. I was in a pinch.

Comment: Copy and paste the definition? [Screen readers](http://www.afb.org/prodBrowseCatResults.aspx?CatID=49), i.e. the programme used by many blind or people whose eyesight is severely impaired, do not read images.

Comment: I would say there's about a 50% chance that the term is derived from American baseball (or possibly British cricket).

Answer (score 2):

This is just a quick answer:

To be the mustard = to be special (circa 1903)

To cut the mustard = to succeed (1907)

To cut it = to succeed (once the previous idiom was established)

To hack it = to cope (circa 1955)

Answer (score 0):

The expression appears to be an AmE one from the ‘50s. The Phrase Finder suggests a possible derivation from an earlier and even more mysterious expression “[can’t cut the musturd](http://www.dictionary.com/e/cut-the-mustard/)” with the same meaning:

[Can’t hack it](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hack&allowed_in_frame=0) :

> - Slang sense of "cope with" (as in can't hack it) is first recorded in American English 1955.

From the Phrase Finder:

> The Oxford English Dictionary, after giving the principle uses of "hack", such as chop or chop at, mutilate with jagged strokes, give us this:
>
> d) To cope with, manage, accomplish; to tolerate, accept; to comprehend; freq. to hack it. slang (orig. U.S.):
>
> - *: 1955 Antioch Rev. XV. 379, I can't hack something like stealing.*. .
>
> If, as seems likely, "[can't hack it](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/58/messages/1100.html)" originated as American slang in the 1940s or '50s, it probably was introduced as a variation on "can't cut it" (with the same meaning). The *it* in "can't cut it" is *the mustard*; and the phrase "cut the mustard" is wreathed in mysteries as well.

Also, from [dailywritingtips](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/what-is-the-meaning-of-hack/):

> - One school of thought is that hack simply derives from an Old High German word that refers to chopping. (A short, sharp cough is also called a hack.) From that meaning, it derived the figurative sense of crudely or ruthlessly working on something and then of simply toiling; ***by extension, the word was applied to being able or unable to manage or tolerate something: The now-rare expression “You just can’t hack it” expressed this idea.***

Comment: great answer thanks.   (1)  "The now-rare expression" what the hell are they talking about?  (2) "A short, sharp cough is also called a hack." - why did they add that parenthesis?  It has nothing, whatsoever, to do with anything under discussion.  Bizarre

Comment: You're saying it's not at all rare, right?